# Netbeans + ZF2 - Type hinting in view files

Tags: zend-framework2, netbeans-8, type-hinting

The task is simple, I want to add type hinting in Netbeans so I can get code assist in view files. How to do it the right way? The example below does not work:

```
/**
 * @var \Zend\Paginator\Paginator $this->paginator
 */
$pageOffset = ($this->paginator->getCurrentPageNumber() - 1) * $this->paginator->getItemCountPerPage();
```

This is done in `phtml` file not php class file.

Answer (score 2):

Many IDEs fail to provide type hinting for view properties in view files.

One workaround would be to assign the property of the view class to a new variable at the top of the view file.

```
/**
 * @var \Zend\Paginator\Paginator $paginator
 */
$paginator = $this->paginator;
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong order. Variable name comes first, then the type. Also write it in one line.

```
/* @var $this->paginator \Zend\Paginator\Paginator */
```